# Missing opencv core .so library in .aar

Tags: android, opencv, cmake, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I'm currently trying to compile OpenCV using Gradle and integrate it within my Android project, but I'm facing an issue and I don't know how to resolve it.

I have created a native library module within my project and created a few gradle tasks for downloading and unzipping the source code within the project. Then, using the CMakeLists.txt file provided in the OpenCV project, I import it using "add_subdirectory" within my application CMakeList.txt file.

With this, the OpenCV compilation complete correctly and generates the two required libraries, *libopencv_core.so* and *libopencv_imgproc.so* in the ***.cxx/RELEASE/buildHash/arm64-v8a/opencv/lib/arm64-v8a/*** folder

However, only my own application .so library and the *libopencv_imgproc.so* are included in the final .aar file. The *libopencv_core.so* is missing. If I check in the Gradle build folder, located in ***build/intermediates/cxx/RELEASE/buildHash/obj/arm64-v8a/***, I can see the same issue as in the .aar.

The funny thing is, if I only require to use the *libopencv_core.so*, it will be integrated within the final .aar correctly, and I don't understand why.

Here is my CMakeList.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18.1)

project("myapp")

add_library(
        myapp
        SHARED
        myapp.cpp )

find_library(
        log-lib
        log )

# OpenCV source code and CMakeList.txt are located in the opencv folder
add_subdirectory(opencv)

# Library opencv_core and opencv_imgproc are generated by the OpenCV CMakeList.txt
target_link_libraries(myapp opencv_core opencv_imgproc ${log-lib} )

target_include_directories(myapp PUBLIC
        opencv/modules/core/include
        opencv/modules/imgproc/include
)

include_directories (${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
```

My question is, what am I missing ? Is there something I must specify to force the inclusion of the *libopencv_core.so* ?

PS: Why I'm not simply integrating the binaries instead of compiling them ? Because the app is targeted for F-Droid, which requires to whole code to be compiled from the sources, so this is not an option for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally managed to copy the libopencv_core.so in the correct folder and generate a complete aar.

I just had to add the following to my application CMakeLists.txt:

`set_target_properties( opencv_core PROPERTIES LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY} )`

I don't really get why I must add this line, but it's working !

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).